# Javascript extract information from RegExp class

Tags: javascript, regex

Hy guys,
I have this regular expression in javascript

```
var regexp = new RegExp('[a-z]{2}');
```

Is there a way to extract the min length of this? In this case is "2", but could me any number.

Tks.

Comment: JS provides no direct way to know the minimum length of a string which matches an arbitrary regex. But I guess it would be possible to use some JS implementation of a regex parser, and modify it slightly to calculate this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume, you don't have direct access to the string literal, in that case you can use the `source` property of the regex to get the string source

```js
var regexp = new RegExp('[a-z]{2}');
var num = regexp.source.match(/\{(\d+)\}/)[1];

snippet.log('Number: ' + num)
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

---

But if you have access to the string literal then you can directly use that string literal

```js
var string = '[a-z]{2}';
var regexp = new RegExp(string);
var num = string.match(/\{(\d+)\}/)[1];

snippet.log('Number: ' + num)
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: Wow! Awesome and simple. Yes, I don't have access to the string literal.
Does it work with any regex?

Comment: You can't determine the min length from `[a-z]\d` using the approach above.